# Are there any editors that does syntax highlighting for Django templates?

Tags: python, django

Like of I put my cursor on an opening forloop tag the closing forloop tag will be highlighted like most IDEs?

Preferably free.

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head I know [Vim](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/UsingVimWithDjango), [Emacs](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Emacs), [Textmate](https://bitbucket.org/bkerr/django-textmate-bundles/overview/) and [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) all support Django's template syntax, and I'd imagine many more do as well. They all support customizable syntax highlighting/completion. I've been particularly impressed with PyCharm's Django support, but there are many good IDEs/Editors out there. Pick one, and then look around a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Pydev author's post [here](http://pydev.blogspot.com/2010/08/django-templates-editor.html) says pydev featured in Aptana Studio 3 has it.

Answer (score 0):

[KomodoEdit](http://www.openkomodo.com/) should have not only syntax highlighting, but even autocompletion for django templatetags and filters. Also, it highlights syntax (and autocompletes) in files with mixture of languages which is especially useful when working with django templates, where you frequently need to edit code in three or four languages (django/html/css/javascript).